# Каверзный Jquery $.load (или $.get)

Tags: javascript, jquery

При загрузки контента со сторонней страницы обнаружил такую проблему.
Он загружает первый генерируемый код HTML не дожидаясь загрузки скриптов на сторонней странице.

Если подробнее. На загружаемой странице page.php есть срипты которые после загрузки страницы генерируют какой-то контент.

Получается что если мы выполняем на странице index.php скрипт $.load ("page.php"); то мы получаем контент до обработки скриптами на странице page.php

Кто сталкивался и как решается?

Comment: Это логично, так как скрипты выполняются браузерным движком для JavaScript, а не сервером или php. Если не ошибаюсь скрипты должны быть выполнены после того, как загруженная страница будет вставлена в dom-дерево и если этого не происходит, надо смотреть почему.

Comment: Точно. Вот я торможу. Конечно браузерным движком!